# How to sort row values of a pandas dataframe based on conditions?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1','aa', 'fff'], ['1', 'aa', 'ggg'], ['1', 'aa', 'eee'],
           ['2','aa', 'eee'], ['2', 'aa', 'ggg'], ['2', 'aa', 'fff'],
           ['3','bb', 'hhh'], ['3', 'bb', 'mmm'], ['3', 'bb', 'kkk'],
           ['3', 'bb', 'jjj'], ['4','bb', 'kkk'], ['4', 'bb', 'mmm'],
           ['4', 'bb', 'hhh'], ['4', 'bb', 'jjj'], ['5','aa', 'ggg'],
           ['5', 'aa', 'eee'], ['5', 'aa', 'fff']], columns=['foo', 'bar','name_input'])
```

Now, I need to sort values in column "name_input" based on a condition.
The condition is

- for bar == aa , then row values == ['eee', 'fff', 'ggg'] and for bar == bb, then row values == ['hhh' ,'jjj', 'kkk','mmm']

In the end, I am aiming to have my output as following

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1','aa', 'eee'], ['1', 'aa', 'fff'], ['1', 'aa', 'ggg'],
           ['2','aa', 'eee'], ['2', 'aa', 'fff'], ['2', 'aa', 'ggg'],
           ['3','bb', 'hhh'], ['3', 'bb', 'jjj'], ['3', 'bb', 'kkk'],
           ['3', 'bb', 'mmm'], ['4','bb', 'hhh'], ['4', 'bb', 'jjj'],
           ['4', 'bb', 'kkk'], ['4', 'bb', 'mmm'], ['5','aa', 'eee'],
           ['5', 'aa', 'fff'], ['5', 'aa', 'ggg']], columns=['foo', 'bar','name_input'])
```

I tried reorder index by rows. However it doesn't seem to work.

```
df = df.pivot(index="foo", columns="bar", values="name_input")
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understood, you would want to groupby and then convert the desired (*to be sorted*) column to [`categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Categorical.html) , then  [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
d = {'aa':['eee', 'fff', 'ggg'],'bb':['hhh' ,'jjj', 'kkk','mmm']} #dict of the conditions

final = pd.concat(g.reset_index().assign(name_input = 
            pd.Categorical(g.reset_index()['name_input'],d.get(i),ordered=True))
           .sort_values('name_input') for i,g in 
           df.set_index('name_input').groupby(['foo','bar'])).reindex(df.columns,axis=1)
```

---

```
  foo bar name_input
2   1  aa        eee
0   1  aa        fff
1   1  aa        ggg
0   2  aa        eee
2   2  aa        fff
1   2  aa        ggg
0   3  bb        hhh
3   3  bb        jjj
2   3  bb        kkk
1   3  bb        mmm
2   4  bb        hhh
3   4  bb        jjj
0   4  bb        kkk
1   4  bb        mmm
1   5  aa        eee
2   5  aa        fff
0   5  aa        ggg
```

Comment: nice, I was thinking of converting the df to dict and then using a custom sort with the `sorted` class but this is better

Comment: @Datanovice this follows a similar logic but little different. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal

dt = df.sort_values(by=['foo', 'bar', 'name_input']).reset_index().drop('index', axis=1, inplace=False)

try:
    assert_frame_equal(dt, df)
    print("True")
except:  
    print("False")

>>>True
```